# Fetch API await chunk of defined chunk size

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch, fetch-api

I want to fetch an URL and process the response in chunks of a defined size. I also don't want to block while waiting for the whole chunk to be available. Is something like this available in the Fetch API?

Example how it could look like:

```js
const response = await fetch(url)
const reader = response.body.getReader()
const chunk = await reader.read(CHUNK_SIZE)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is support in fetch() to be consumed like a stream. See [MDN reference here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API/Using_readable_streams#consuming_a_fetch_as_a_stream). It appears that you need some boilerplate code for ReadableStream...

Code would like this:

```js
const workOnChunk = (chunk) => { console.log("do-work")};

// Fetch your stuff  
fetch(url)
// Retrieve its body as ReadableStream
.then(response => response.body)

// Boilerplate for the stream - refactor it out in a common utility.
.then(rs => {
  const reader = rs.getReader();

  return new ReadableStream({
    async start(controller) {
      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();

        // When no more data needs to be consumed, break the reading
        if (done) {
          break;
        }

        // Do your work: ¿¿ Checkout what value returns ¿¿
        workOnChunk(value)

        // Optionally append the value if you need the full blob later.
        controller.enqueue(value);
      }

      // Close the stream
      controller.close();
      reader.releaseLock();
    }
  })
})
// Create a new response out of the stream (can be avoided?)
.then(rs => new Response(rs))
// Create an object URL for the response
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => { console.log("Do something with full blob") }
.catch(console.error)
```

---

NOTE: The nodejs-fetch API is not exactly the same. If you are on nodejs, see [nodeje-fetch's stream support](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#streams).

Comment: In your example, `await reader.read()` will read whatever bytes are available? I want to await until there is at least `CHUNK_SIZE` bytes available.

Comment: It would provide you with whatever is available. You can possibly `check the length` of chunk and decide to process it or queue it in a list until it's of size.

Comment: `...and process the response in chunks of a defined size.`
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ReadableStream/ReadableStream#queuingstrategy